# Visual studio Find files that does NOT contain X

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, find

I need a way to list all files that does **NOT** contain a known text.

The project contains over 1000 files and I only want the ones that does not contain some text.

I thought of Regular expressions, but it doesn't have such a feature.

Anyone knows a solution?

Comment: It's not VS but Windows Grep has a feature that lets you invert a match: http://www.wingrep.com/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From a command prompt:

```
@for /r %f in (FILE_SPECIFIER) do @find "YOUR_STRING" "%f" > nul || echo %f
```

For example:

```
C:\web-trunk\Views>@for /r %f in (*.cshtml) do @find "Layout" "%f" > nul || echo %f

C:\data\web-trunk\Views\Account\RegisterPartial.cshtml
C:\data\web-trunk\Views\Admin\SiteInspector.cshtml
C:\data\web-trunk\Views\CandidateProfile\View.cshtml
C:\data\web-trunk\Views\Common\ContactFooterForInfoEmails.cshtml
C:\data\web-trunk\Views\Common\ContactFooterForInfoPages.cshtml
C:\data\web-trunk\Views\Common\ContactFooterForSalesEmails.cshtml
C:\data\web-trunk\Views\Common\ContactFooterForSalesPages.cshtml
```

[Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for) on this method can help finding the best file search term for you.

Comment: Any idea on how to still find files that don't contain particular text, but to also exclude certain file types (in addition to including certain file types)?

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: as Peter McVoy pointed out, this solution does not work. It will return false positives (files that contain a line without the text to search for will also be printed). A VS macro or a custom powershell script is probably the way to go. I might revisit this answer later.

For reference, this was my answer:

*You can do this on the command line:*

```
findstr /S /V /M text_to_search_for *.cs
```

*This will print all filenames that do not contain the text*

Comment: I was hoping for a build-in Visual Studio solution, where I can open my files easily, but this will do for now.

Comment: Won't this just list files that have lines that don't contain the search text?  IE a file which has one line without the search text will be listed even if it has it elsewhere in the file

Comment: @Peter McEvoy: good catch! Edited. @jerone pls unaccept this answer as it's wrong...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Find in Files](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/searching/searching-files) feature of [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Steps:

1. Type in the word you want to find and select the directory.
2. Copy the search result.
3. Filter it to retrieve the file list *containing* the word.
4. And then run a simple loop in C# to get the list of files that *are not* in this list. These are the files that do not contain the word.

Here is the loop to get the files list is (searches in `.cs` files) (can be optimized):

```
private void GetFileNamesNotContainingWord(string filePath, string searchDirectoryPath, string notContainingFilePath)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
    List<string> filesList = new List<string>();

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (!line.StartsWith("\t"))
        {
            filesList.Add(line.Substring(0, line.LastIndexOf('(')).Trim());
        }
    }

    List<string> notContainedFiles = new List<string>();
    foreach (FileInfo file in new DirectoryInfo(searchDirectoryPath).GetFiles("*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        if (!filesList.Contains(file.FullName))
        {
            notContainedFiles.Add(file.FullName);
        }
    }

    File.WriteAllLines(notContainingFilePath, notContainedFiles.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: This approach is possible also with Visual Studio, no need to suggest to use an additional tool here. One can use a global search to get both a list of all files of the project, and a list of files containing the text. The interesting question is: is there a builtin functionality which helps to "substract" the 2nd list from the first?

Answer (score 1):

Use **find** or **findstr** from a command window ('DOS box').