# How to find all files that do NOT contain specific string in windows environment Visual Studio or any other IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, search, find

How do you search in Visual Studio all files with certain extension that do NOT contain a specific string? Find in Files feature in visual studio ( VS 2008 or VS 2010 or VS 2012) has regex option but I did not see a way to find files that do not contain a string.
I need to find in a project folder with thousands of files which aspx.cs files do not contain the string 'security'. I found some solutions no for windows platform, and was wondering how to do this on a windows machine and ideally without paying for an application? I also found another old posts on stackoverflow with wrong answers, and also used windows grep app and it did not work:
[Visual studio Find files that does NOT contain X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909714/visual-studio-find-files-that-does-not-contain-x)

The solution also applies to this post: How to use Notepad++ to find files in a directory that do not contain string :
https://superuser.com/questions/110350/how-to-use-notepad-to-find-files-in-a-directory-that-do-not-contain-string :

*@Peter McEvoy: good catch! @jerone pls unaccept this answer as it's wrong... – jeroenh. this solution does not work. It will return false positives*

Comment: VS doesn't have this feature.  You could write a macro but inverting the list by hand is surely quicker.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally found solution to find all files with certain extension that do NOT contain a specific string, I was looking for a solution to this for a long time, and it works great and is free. 
Hope this helps others who are trying to do the same.

```
GOTO EndComment
1st Change source, destination, extension and string to your needs.
2nd Remove ECHO from line 19 (If you want to make a copy of those 
specific files that contain the string to destination folder)
3rd Save this piece of code on a file file with extension .cmd 
    and run it to get results (just double click on file).
:EndComment

@echo off
setlocal

set source=c:\Users\youruseraccount\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\PathofProject\
set destination=c:\foundFilesWithoutString\
set extension=*.aspx.cs
set string=Security

for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /s "%source%\%extension%" /a:-d /b') do ( 
  find /c /i "%string%" "%%G" > NUL || (
  ECHO copy "%%G" "%destination%" 
 ) 
) 


pause
```

Comment: Your answer does not iterate recursively; to do so use following for loop -- for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /s "%source%\%extension%" /a:-d /b') do (
  find /c /i "%string%" "%%G" > NUL || (
  ECHO copy "%%G" "%destination%"
 )
)

Comment: It's too bad you replaced the "search only current directory" option with the "also search sub-directories" option, as the OP didn't explicitly ask for it, and I currently need it.  So, I need to work backwards from your final solution to determine what the command looks like to only search the current folder.

Comment: For those who need the current-directory version, change "dir /s" to just "dir" in the for loop.

Answer (score -2):

There is an extension for visual studio code for finding files that don't contain specific string [Reverse Search](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanishSarwar.reverse-search)

Comment: Reverse Search didn't work for me in latest VS Code on a Mac OS.